# Tikz .tex file for a ggplot image made in R won't render as pdf in my tex document (but no compile error!)

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, r

I'll preface by saying that I'm not sure whether this is better off posted in StackOverflow, and I'd be happy to move it over there if that turns out to be the case.

**tl;dr**

I followed the instructions for getting a ggplot image into a Latex document, but when I render/compile the PDF, the image doesn't show -- even after Texmaker compiled without error!

**Useful Background, maybe**

My LaTeX setup is MikTek on Windows; I do my writing in Texmaker; and I compile using XeLaTex and BibTex. I'm still pretty new to LaTeX overall (<3 months), but I love it overall and I'm devoted to learning.

**Situation**

I have a nice looking graph I made in ggplot, and I want to get it into my LaTeX document. After some research, I landed on the Tikz environment and followed the instruction in the documentation and various people's blogs to A) convert the plot into a `.tex` file in R and B) import that `.tex` file into my Latex document and render it into PDF.

That first part is usually done with some code that looks like this:

```
tikz(file = "plot_test.tex", width = 5, height = 5)
    #Simple plot of the dummy data using LaTeX elements
    plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
        geom_line() +
        #Space does not appear after Latex
        ggtitle( paste("Fancy \\LaTeX ", "\\hspace{0.01cm} title")) +
        labs( x = "$x$ = Time", y = "$\\Phi$ = Innovation output") +
        theme_bw()
    #This line is only necessary if you want to preview the plot right after compiling
    print(plot)
    #Necessary to close or the tikxDevice .tex file will not be written
    dev.off()
```

And the second part is supposed to be done like so:

```
 documentclass{article}
    %The package tikz is available in pgf
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
        %Do not try to scale figure in .tex or you loose font size consistency
            \centering
        %The code to input the plot is extremely simple
        \input{plot_test.tex}
        %Captions and Labels can be used since this is a figure environment
        \caption{Sample output from tikzDevice}
        \label{plot:test}
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

**My Own Code**

First, here's a sample comma-separated dataframe (per a user's comment below):

```
year,rate,study
1987,0.01,41
1987,0.01,842
1987,0.02,833
1987,0.01,864
1988,,
1989,,
1990,,
1991,0.03,682
1991,0.03,173
1991,0.02,714
1992,,
1993,,
1994,,
1995,,
1996,0.03,91
1996,0.06,162
1996,0.06,263
1996,0.05,914
1997,0.05,55
1998,,
1999,,
2000,,
2001,,
2002,0.06,746
2003,,
2004,0.07,5
2004,0.08,557
2005,,
2006,,
2007,,
2008,,
2009,,
2010,,
2011,0.08,95
2012,,
2013,,
2014,0.09,7
2015,,
2016,,
```

I modeled my own code after the instructions I found in the documentation and on the web. R/ggplot to .tex:

```
tikz(file = 'plot.tex', width = 5, height = 5, sanitize = TRUE)
plot <- ggplot(data = data[!is.na(data$rate), ], aes(year, rate)) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(color = study)) +
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE, color = "grey50", size=0.5, linetype = "twodash") +
  labs(
    x = "Year",
    y = "Proportion"
  ) + 
  theme_light()
dev.off()
```

I move the new `ggplot` `.tex`file into the document's home directory. Then I use this Latex code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Adobe Garamond Pro}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage[left]{lineno}
\linenumbers
\doublespacing
\usepackage{anysize}



\begin{figure}
\centering
\input{plot.tex}
\caption{Trying to get Tikz to work}
\end{figure}
```

I then compile using XeLaTex, and it does so without any errors. But when I click "View PDF" in TexMaker (or actually open the pdf from the document's directory), I see nothing. Curiously, the caption "Trying to get Tikz to work" **does** show in the document!

Anyone have any ideas? I've gone through posts all over SX (and elsewhere) on this, but couldn't find any that matched my current situation.

**Supplementary Material**

Someone suggested that I include the contents of the file that `R` and `tikzDevice` created, so here it is! (It's long, sorry).

```
% Created by tikzDevice version 0.12 on 2019-04-22 13:43:13
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt,y=1pt]
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}
\path[use as bounding box,fill=fillColor,fill opacity=0.00] (0,0) rectangle (252.94,252.94);
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] (  0.00,  0.00) rectangle (252.94,252.94);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.6pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] (  0.00, -0.00) rectangle (252.94,252.94);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] ( 42.77, 30.73) rectangle (192.29,247.45);
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\path[fill=fillColor] ( 42.77, 30.73) rectangle (192.29,247.45);
\definecolor{drawColor}{gray}{0.87}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.1pt,line join=round] ( 42.77, 46.74) --
    (192.29, 46.74);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.1pt,line join=round] ( 42.77,108.30) --
    (192.29,108.30);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.1pt,line join=round] ( 42.77,169.87) --
    (192.29,169.87);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.1pt,line join=round] ( 42.77,231.44) --
    (192.29,231.44);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.1pt,line join=round] ( 52.08, 30.73) --
    ( 52.08,247.45);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.1pt,line join=round] ( 77.25, 30.73) --
    ( 77.25,247.45);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.1pt,line join=round] (102.43, 30.73) --
    (102.43,247.45);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.1pt,line join=round] (127.60, 30.73) --
    (127.60,247.45);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.1pt,line join=round] (152.77, 30.73) --
    (152.77,247.45);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.1pt,line join=round] (177.94, 30.73) --
    (177.94,247.45);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.3pt,line join=round] ( 42.77, 77.52) --
    (192.29, 77.52);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.3pt,line join=round] ( 42.77,139.09) --
    (192.29,139.09);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.3pt,line join=round] ( 42.77,200.65) --
    (192.29,200.65);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.3pt,line join=round] ( 64.67, 30.73) --
    ( 64.67,247.45);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.3pt,line join=round] ( 89.84, 30.73) --
    ( 89.84,247.45);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.3pt,line join=round] (115.01, 30.73) --
    (115.01,247.45);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.3pt,line join=round] (140.18, 30.73) --
    (140.18,247.45);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.3pt,line join=round] (165.36, 30.73) --
    (165.36,247.45);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.3pt,line join=round] (190.53, 30.73) --
    (190.53,247.45);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{21,48,73}
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{21,48,73}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] ( 49.56, 40.58) circle (  1.96);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{80,165,231}
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{80,165,231}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] ( 49.56, 40.58) circle (  1.96);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{80,164,229}
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{80,164,229}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] ( 49.56, 65.21) circle (  1.96);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{82,169,236}
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{82,169,236}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] ( 49.56, 40.58) circle (  1.96);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{68,140,197}
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{68,140,197}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] ( 69.70, 89.83) circle (  1.96);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{30,65,97}
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{30,65,97}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] ( 69.70, 89.83) circle (  1.96);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{70,145,204}
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{70,145,204}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] ( 69.70, 65.21) circle (  1.96);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{25,54,82}
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{25,54,82}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] ( 94.87, 89.83) circle (  1.96);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{30,64,95}
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{30,64,95}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] ( 94.87,163.71) circle (  1.96);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{37,78,114}
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{37,78,114}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] ( 94.87,163.71) circle (  1.96);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{86,177,247}
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{86,177,247}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] ( 94.87,139.09) circle (  1.96);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{22,49,76}
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{22,49,76}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] ( 99.91,139.09) circle (  1.96);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{73,150,211}
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{73,150,211}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] (125.08,163.71) circle (  1.96);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{19,43,67}
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{19,43,67}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] (135.15,188.34) circle (  1.96);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{58,121,172}
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{58,121,172}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] (135.15,212.97) circle (  1.96);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{25,55,83}
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{25,55,83}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] (170.39,212.97) circle (  1.96);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{19,43,67}
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{19,43,67}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.4pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] (185.49,237.59) circle (  1.96);
\definecolor{drawColor}{gray}{0.50}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.6pt,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt on 6pt off 2pt ,line join=round] ( 49.56, 46.74) --
    ( 51.28, 49.33) --
    ( 53.00, 52.00) --
    ( 54.73, 54.74) --
    ( 56.45, 57.55) --
    ( 58.17, 60.44) --
    ( 59.89, 63.39) --
    ( 61.61, 66.42) --
    ( 63.33, 69.52) --
    ( 65.05, 72.69) --
    ( 66.77, 75.93) --
    ( 68.49, 79.25) --
    ( 70.21, 82.64) --
    ( 71.93, 86.22) --
    ( 73.65, 89.98) --
    ( 75.37, 93.90) --
    ( 77.09, 97.92) --
    ( 78.81,102.03) --
    ( 80.53,106.17) --
    ( 82.26,110.32) --
    ( 83.98,114.43) --
    ( 85.70,118.47) --
    ( 87.42,122.39) --
    ( 89.14,126.18) --
    ( 90.86,129.77) --
    ( 92.58,133.15) --
    ( 94.30,136.27) --
    ( 96.02,139.14) --
    ( 97.74,141.91) --
    ( 99.46,144.59) --
    (101.18,147.19) --
    (102.90,149.72) --
    (104.62,152.19) --
    (106.34,154.60) --
    (108.07,156.97) --
    (109.79,159.29) --
    (111.51,161.58) --
    (113.23,163.84) --
    (114.95,166.08) --
    (116.67,168.31) --
    (118.39,170.54) --
    (120.11,172.77) --
    (121.83,175.01) --
    (123.55,177.28) --
    (125.27,179.56) --
    (126.99,181.83) --
    (128.71,184.05) --
    (130.43,186.21) --
    (132.15,188.29) --
    (133.87,190.28) --
    (135.60,192.17) --
    (137.32,194.00) --
    (139.04,195.81) --
    (140.76,197.58) --
    (142.48,199.33) --
    (144.20,201.04) --
    (145.92,202.72) --
    (147.64,204.37) --
    (149.36,205.98) --
    (151.08,207.57) --
    (152.80,209.12) --
    (154.52,210.64) --
    (156.24,212.12) --
    (157.96,213.58) --
    (159.68,215.00) --
    (161.41,216.39) --
    (163.13,217.75) --
    (164.85,219.08) --
    (166.57,220.37) --
    (168.29,221.63) --
    (170.01,222.86) --
    (171.73,224.05) --
    (173.45,225.22) --
    (175.17,226.35) --
    (176.89,227.44) --
    (178.61,228.51) --
    (180.33,229.54) --
    (182.05,230.54) --
    (183.77,231.50) --
    (185.49,232.43);
\definecolor{drawColor}{gray}{0.70}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.6pt,line join=round,line cap=round] ( 42.77, 30.73) rectangle (192.29,247.45);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] (  0.00,  0.00) rectangle (252.94,252.94);
\definecolor{drawColor}{gray}{0.30}

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base east,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  0.88] at ( 37.82, 74.49) {0.025};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base east,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  0.88] at ( 37.82,136.06) {0.050};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base east,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  0.88] at ( 37.82,197.62) {0.075};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] (  0.00,  0.00) rectangle (252.94,252.94);
\definecolor{drawColor}{gray}{0.70}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.3pt,line join=round] ( 40.02, 77.52) --
    ( 42.77, 77.52);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.3pt,line join=round] ( 40.02,139.09) --
    ( 42.77,139.09);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.3pt,line join=round] ( 40.02,200.65) --
    ( 42.77,200.65);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] (  0.00,  0.00) rectangle (252.94,252.94);
\definecolor{drawColor}{gray}{0.70}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.3pt,line join=round] ( 64.67, 27.98) --
    ( 64.67, 30.73);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.3pt,line join=round] ( 89.84, 27.98) --
    ( 89.84, 30.73);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.3pt,line join=round] (115.01, 27.98) --
    (115.01, 30.73);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.3pt,line join=round] (140.18, 27.98) --
    (140.18, 30.73);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.3pt,line join=round] (165.36, 27.98) --
    (165.36, 30.73);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.3pt,line join=round] (190.53, 27.98) --
    (190.53, 30.73);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] (  0.00,  0.00) rectangle (252.94,252.94);
\definecolor{drawColor}{gray}{0.30}

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  0.88] at ( 64.67, 19.72) {1990};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  0.88] at ( 89.84, 19.72) {1995};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  0.88] at (115.01, 19.72) {2000};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  0.88] at (140.18, 19.72) {2005};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  0.88] at (165.36, 19.72) {2010};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  0.88] at (190.53, 19.72) {2015};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] (  0.00,  0.00) rectangle (252.94,252.94);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{0,0,0}

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.10] at (117.53,  7.44) {Year};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] (  0.00,  0.00) rectangle (252.94,252.94);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{0,0,0}

\node[text=drawColor,rotate= 90.00,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.10] at ( 13.08,139.09) {Proportion};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] (  0.00,  0.00) rectangle (252.94,252.94);
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\path[fill=fillColor] (203.29, 89.94) rectangle (247.44,188.23);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] (  0.00,  0.00) rectangle (252.94,252.94);
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,anchor=south west,rotate=  0.00] at (208.79,  95.44) {
    \pgfimage[width= 14.45pt,height= 72.27pt,interpolate=true]{plot_ras1}};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] (  0.00,  0.00) rectangle (252.94,252.94);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{0,0,0}

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base west,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  0.88] at (228.74,112.72) {250};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base west,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  0.88] at (228.74,131.60) {500};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base west,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  0.88] at (228.74,150.49) {750};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] (  0.00,  0.00) rectangle (252.94,252.94);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{0,0,0}

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base west,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.10] at (208.79,174.18) {study};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] (  0.00,  0.00) rectangle (252.94,252.94);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.2pt,line join=round] (208.79,115.75) -- (211.68,115.75);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.2pt,line join=round] (208.79,134.63) -- (211.68,134.63);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.2pt,line join=round] (208.79,153.52) -- (211.68,153.52);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.2pt,line join=round] (220.35,115.75) -- (223.24,115.75);

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.2pt,line join=round] (220.35,134.63) -- (223.24,134.63);

\path[draw=draw
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Questions about R+LaTeX are generally on topic here, so you're in the right place. Could you add a sample data frame to your example code?  BTW, you can format code by selecting it and clicking on the `{}` icon. Backticks are for inline code only. Also instead of posting your whole preamble, make a compilable document that shows the result with the minimal preamble you can make.

Comment: so people without R can debug your problem it is best to post the generated tikz file and a small but complete latex document that inputs it, the R code and all the rest of your preamble should not be needed.

Comment: Re: code formatting: got it! Didn't realize. Will change. Re: sample dataframe: yeah, absolutely, let me dig something up.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the generated Tikz file is 300+ lines long. You really want me to paste it in here?

Comment: Up to you, most people won't have R so more people can answer if you have a pure latex example that shows the problem, on the other hand if it's bad tikz then people can not suggest changes to the R if you don't show it:-) perhaps just go with the R version initially, see if someone answers...

Comment: Frankly, I'm a bit desperate here, so I'll drop it in. Thanks!

Comment: Did your supplementary material truncate strangely?  Would it be possible to just use the first 11 lines of your sample csv, and see what that gives you?

Comment: your plot.tex ends with `\path[draw=draw` and no close to that argument.

Comment: I don't know what you're plotting, but a few times I've seen R generate tikz which is enormous, and which upon further inspection could be plotted very easily by getting the generated data out of R and then plotting it with pgfplots

Comment: You need to install the dev version of TikZDevice from Github. It hasn't been released to CRAN yet.

Comment: That's version 0.12.2. You have 0.12.

Comment: I first read "... new to LaTeX overall (❤️ months), but I love it ..." and I was like "what's '❤️ months' supposed to mean?!"

Comment: Also, sorry I can't help you any further. I don't know enough R, yet, and have also not looked into knitr and sweave and TikZDevice.

Answer (score 1):

[image: mwe]

Really it is much more simple that you tried. Be sure that you have installed `knitr` and `tikzDevice` in R, and compile this`test.Rnw` file in Rstudio:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<test, echo=F,dev='tikz',message=FALSE,fig.width=2.5, fig.height=2.5  >>=
# install.packages("tikzDevice")
require(ggplot2)
data <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5), y=c(1,2,4,4,5))
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
        geom_line() +
        ggtitle("Fancy \\LaTeX\\ title") +
        labs( x = "$x$ = Time", y = "$\\Phi$ = Innovation output") +
        theme_bw()
@
\end{document}
```